# ASP .Net core 1.1: How to use WebAPI in Web Application

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-webapi

I'm sorry if it's a foolish question. But I'm a very newbie in .net core and really want to know how to do it.

I've created a simple WebAPI on Visual Studio 2017 Community, which get some information from database and return a list of object as json format. It ran ok and I got a .dll file with some .json files in Release folder.

And now I want to create a .net core web app which use WebAPI above to receive data and display for user. What should I do? And how to set it up?

Many thanks!

Comment: you can call it to controller by url or the same way for jquery

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are few simple steps,

1. Create an instance of HttpClient 
   `static HttpClient client = new HttpClient();`
2. Set the required base address of the Web Api and also set the authorization headers and media headers as per requirement

   ```
   client.BaseAddress = new Uri("http://localhost:55268/");
   client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Clear();
   client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new 
     MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));
   ```
3. Make a request and get the response, ensure that the response is indicating success, else act accordingly

   ```
   Product product = null;
   HttpResponseMessage response = await client.GetAsync(path);
   if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
   {
     product = await response.Content.ReadAsAsync<Product>();
   }
   return product;
   ```

You can use any serializer to de-serialize the API response to your required business model.

You can learn more from [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-api/overview/advanced/calling-a-web-api-from-a-net-client)

HTH

Comment: Also, you need to launch both application (Web API +Web APP)

Comment: Yes, right, have the multiple startup projects enabled and ordered in the solution